# I'm trying to apply Bernoulli's method of substitution to this nonlinear de but I can't seem to cancel out the dependent variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y' = y(xy^3-1)$

When I substitute variable $v'$, I get
$-3v^{-4} dv/dx - (2/x) v^{-3} = (3/x^2) v^{-12}$

According, to Bernoulli's method, the v on the RHS should cancel out after dividing through by the coefficient of dv/dx but in this case it doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y' = y(xy^3-1)$$
$$y' =xy^4-y$$
$$\dfrac {y'}{y^4} =x-\dfrac 1 {y^3}$$
Substitute  $v=\dfrac 1 {y^3}$ and $v'=\dfrac {-3y'}{y^4}$

Then the ODE becomes a first order linear DE.
$$v'-3v=-3x$$
$$(ve^{-3x})'=-3xe^{-3x}$$
Integrate.